# "syntax enable" only works in normal mode, not in vimrc

Tags: vim

No idea how I've just broken my vimrc, but I have. I have solarized installed, but syntax highlighting is no longer working automatically - I have to retype "syntax enable" every time I open the editor.

My vimrc is below - any help much appreciated!

```
" ----- BASICS  -----
set nocompatible "compatible with vi
if !exists("g:syntax_on") 
    syntax enable
endif

filetype on "QS not sure about this one ! 
set number "add line numbers
set showcmd "show command in bottom bar
set cursorline "highlight cursor line
set wildmenu "commandline tab completion 
set mouse=a "make vim useable with mouse
set backspace=indent,eol,start " make backspace work like in most editors.
set showmatch           " highlight matching [{()}]

" ----- COLORSCHEME -----
let g:solarized_termcolors = 256 
set background=light
colorscheme solarized

    " ------ NAVIGATION -----
" long line navigation in normal mode
nnoremap j gj 
nnoremap k gk

" ------ TABS & SPACES -----
set tabstop=4        "number of visual spaces per TAB
set shiftwidth=4 "size of indent with tab
set softtabstop=0 
set noexpandtab "if you are using tab character inside your source
"code - these are defensive settings to avoid conversion

" ---------Searching ----------
set incsearch           " search as characters are entered
set hlsearch            " highlight matches

" ----------Folding ----------- 
set foldenable          " enable folding
set foldlevelstart=10   " open most folds by default
set foldnestmax=10      " 10 nested fold max
nnoremap <space> za     
"space open/closes folds
set foldmethod=indent   " fold based on indent level

set smartindent         " indents your code automatically 
filetype off                  " required
```

Comment: Are you using a terminal emulator that supports 256 colors and you do not want to use the custom Solarized terminal colors?

Comment: what does `:verbose set syntax` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in your `~/.vimrc` disables filetype detection. Without that, Vim treats every opened file as plain text, and therefore does not load any syntax plugin. Drop that line, it doesn't make sense.

```
filetype off                  " required
```

In order to benefit from the built-in *filetype and indent plugins*, rather turn on everything:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

See `:help :filetype` for further details.

Comment: Thanks so much - no idea how/why I dumped that in there!

Comment: Glad I could help; it's always risky to incorporate configuration from somewhere else without understanding it fully. (I've been burned by this, too!)